# iTextSharp: How to resize an image to fit a fix size?

Tags: c#, image, resize, itext

I want to be able to resize an image to the dimension of 159x159 points, using iTextSharp 4.2.0, but the resulting image need to have exactly the dimensions specified.

I've tried this:

```
Image image = Image.GetInstance(imagePath);
image.ScaleAbsolute(159f, 159f);
```

But the image is not a square. It keeps the aspect ratio.

Example:
I have this image:

[image]

And the result image should look loke this:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The problem you describe is typically what happens when you try and add an `Image` directly to a `PdfPTable` by calling `AddCell()`, which **always** scales the image to fit the `PdfPCell`. So if you're adding the image to the `Document` like this:

```
Image img = Image.GetInstance(imagePath);
img.ScaleAbsolute(159f, 159f);
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
table.AddCell(img);
document.Add(table);
```

your `ScaleAbsolute()` call is ignored. To get the scaling you want:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(img));
document.Add(table);
```

Comment: Also be careful don't add image by 'new PdfPCell().setImage(img)', this will add image as the background of the cell, it will auto scaled fit to cell's width and height.

Comment: setting the fit property worked for me: table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(img,true));

Answer (score 9):

**PdfPCell** has property to fit image in cell so just set it to true.

```
  iTextSharp.text.Image logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("/test.png");

  PdfPCell logocell = new PdfPCell(logo,true); //  **PdfPCell(Image,Boolean Fit)**
```