# How to generate PDF one page one row from datatable using iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I created a webforms page that issued many qr voucher codes, what I want is that I can print the vouchers one by one page from the database I have. here's the code I've tried to make

```
Private Sub MySub(Param As String)
        Try
            Dim obj As New ReportObjects
            Dim dt0 As New DataTable
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            ds = obj.MyStoredProcedure(Param)
            obj.Dispose()
            dt0 = ds.Tables(0)
            obj.Dispose()
            dt0.Dispose()
            ds.Dispose()

            For i As Integer = 0 To dt0.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim qrGenerator As QRCodeGenerator = New QRCodeGenerator()
                Dim qrCode As QRCodeGenerator.QRCode = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(dt0.Rows(i).Item("VoucherNo"), QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q)
                Using bitMap As Bitmap = qrCode.GetGraphic(20)
                    Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
                        bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
                        byteImage = ms.ToArray()
                    End Using
                End Using

                Dim base64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage)
                Dim imageBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(base64)
                Dim image As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageBytes)
                Using memoryStream As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream()
                    Dim document As Document = New Document(PageSize.A4, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F)
                    Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream)
                    document.Open()
                    document.NewPage()
                    document.Add(image)
                    document.Add(New Phrase("Valid From : " & dt0.Rows(i).Item("StartDT").ToString() & " To " & dt0.Rows(i).Item("EndDT").ToString()))
                    document.Close()
                    Dim bytes As Byte() = memoryStream.ToArray()
                    memoryStream.Close()
                    Response.Clear()
                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Image.pdf")
                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
                    Response.Buffer = True
                    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
                    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
                    Response.End()
                End Using
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

The problem I encountered with my code is the code doesn't produce multiple pages. It produce just 1 page and the data is the first row of my table. I used iTextSharp for generating PDF.

Your answer will be so helpful. Thank you

Comment: You could try removing the last response.End(). That will terminate the code exception and finish the page round trip to the server. See if it works by commenting out that one line.

Comment: Wow, thank you, I will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following shows how to create a PDF document that has one QR code per page using NuGet packages [iTextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/) and [QRCoder](https://www.nuget.org/packages/QRCoder/). Most of the code is from the OP, however it needed to be rearranged. I added code to allow the size of the QR code to be specified. The code used for testing is included.

The following assumes that you're using a VB.NET `ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)` project. For testing, I used the `Empty` project template. Under "Add folders & core references", I checked **Web Forms**. Under "Advanced", I unchecked **Configure for HTTPS**.

**Open Solution Explorer**

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Solution Explorer**

**Download/install NuGet packages**:

- In Solution Explorer, right-click <solution name>
- Select **Manage NuGet Packages...**
- Click **Browse**
- Search: **QRCoder**
- Select desired version (ex: 1.4.1)
- Click **Install**
- Search: **iTextSharp**
- Select desired version (ex: 5.5.13.2)
- Click **Install**

**Add Webform** (name: default.aspx)

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add New Item...**
- Select **Web Form** (name: default.aspx)
- Click **Add**

**default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="default.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplicationArya._default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnCreateQRCode" Text="Create QRCode" Onclick="btnCreateQRCode_Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Modify default.aspx.vb**

- In Solution Explorer, right-click **default.aspx** and select **View Code**

**default.aspx.vb**

```
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports QRCoder


Public Class _default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Private Function CreateTestData() As DataTable
        Dim dt0 As New DataTable

        'for testing
        dt0.Columns.Add("VoucherNo", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
        dt0.Columns.Add("StartDT", System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime"))
        dt0.Columns.Add("EndDT", System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime"))

        Dim dr As DataRow

        For i As Integer = 0 To 6 Step 1
            'create new row
            dr = dt0.NewRow()
            dr("VoucherNo") = "123" & i.ToString()
            dr("StartDT") = DateTime.Now
            dr("EndDT") = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30)

            'add
            dt0.Rows.Add(dr)
        Next

        Return dt0
    End Function

    Private Sub CreatePdf(dt0 As DataTable, Optional qrCodeSize As Single = 150.0F)
        Dim pdfBytes As Byte() = Nothing
        'Dim writer As PdfWriter = Nothing

        Try
            Using memoryStream As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream()
                Using document As Document = New Document(PageSize.A4, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F)

                    Using writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream)
                        'open
                        document.Open()

                        'create new PDF page for each QRCode
                        For i As Integer = 0 To dt0.Rows.Count - 1 Step 1
                            Dim byteImage As Byte()
                            Dim qrGenerator As QRCodeGenerator = New QRCodeGenerator()

                            'create QRCode for each VoucherNo in DataTable
                            Dim qrGenerator1 As QRCodeGenerator = New QRCodeGenerator()
                            Dim qrCodeData1 As QRCodeData = qrGenerator1.CreateQrCode(dt0.Rows(i).Item("VoucherNo"), QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q)
                            Dim qrCode1 As QRCode = New QRCode(qrCodeData1)
                            Using bitMap As System.Drawing.Bitmap = qrCode1.GetGraphic(20)
                                Using ms As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream()
                                    bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
                                    byteImage = ms.ToArray()
                                End Using
                            End Using

                            Dim image As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(byteImage)

                            'Dim base64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage)
                            'Dim imageBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(base64)
                            'Dim image As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageBytes)

                            'set size
                            'image.ScaleAbsolute(200.0F, 200.0F)

                            'ex: 200.0F, 200.0F
                            image.ScaleAbsolute(qrCodeSize, qrCodeSize)

                            'add new page
                            document.NewPage()

                            'add QRCode image
                            document.Add(image)

                            'add text
                            document.Add(New Phrase("Valid From : " & dt0.Rows(i).Item("StartDT").ToString() & " To " & dt0.Rows(i).Item("EndDT").ToString() & " (image" & i.ToString() & ")"))
                        Next

                        'close
                        document.Close()

                        'convert PDF to byte()
                        pdfBytes = memoryStream.ToArray()
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using

            'send data
            SendData(pdfBytes)

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub SendData(pdfBytes As Byte())
        Response.Clear()
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Image.pdf")
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes)
        'Response.End()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnCreateQRCode_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        'ToDo: Replace "CreateTestData" with function to retrieve data

        'get test data
        Dim dt0 As DataTable = CreateTestData()

        'create PDF containing QRCodes
        'CreatePdf(dt0)

        'create PDF; set size for QR codes
        CreatePdf(dt0, 100.0F)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Note**: You'll need to replace the "CreateTestData" function with a function that retrieves your data.

**Resources**:

- [QRCoder (NuGet)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/QRCoder/)
- [QRCoder (Github)](https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder)
- [How to easily implement QRCoder in ASP.NET Core using C#](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-easily-implement-qrcoder-in-asp-net-core-using-c-10c4aa857e84/)
- [iTextSharp: How to resize an image to fit a fix size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412504/itextsharp-how-to-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-fix-size/45773775)
- [Adding Data to a DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/adding-data-to-a-datatable)
- [DataColumn.DataType Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.datatype?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Wow!!! Thank you so much, It Works!!!