# Is there a way to export QR code as image?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I was trying to export QR code as image inside C: folder. I'm using C# on visual studio and devExpress to create the QR code. I've already created the QR code but I don't know how to export it. Is there a way to do it? Hadn't tried much because I didn't find a lot. Thank you!

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69206917/how-to-generate-pdf-one-page-one-row-from-datatable-using-itextsharp/69218085#69218085

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please check the devexpress documentation, https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport.ExportToImage.overloads and https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/2581/detailed-guide-to-devexpress-reporting/store-and-distribute-reports/export-reports/export-to-image

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to generate barcodes using our WinForms BarCodeControl, use the [BarCodeControl.ExportToImage(Stream, ImageFormat, Int32)](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.BarCodeControl.ExportToImage%28System.IO.Stream-System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat-System.Int32%29?utm_source=SupportCenter&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=docs-feedback&utm_content=T927145) method to export barcode as an image to a stream. after that convert a stream to `byte array` or a `Base64` string.

If you prefer non-visual Barcode Generation API library to create barcodes, use the [BarCode.Save(Stream, ImageFormat)](https://docs.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/DevExpress.BarCodes.BarCode.Save%28System.IO.Stream-System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat%29?utm_source=SupportCenter&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=docs-feedback&utm_content=T927145) method to save the barcode image to a stream in the specified format.Then, convert a stream to a byte array or a Base64 string.

Comment: The last part, when it says 'convert a stream to a byte array or a Base64 string', what does it mean?

Comment: That didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This code belokngs to vb. Net and I'm not using devexpress
Add Zxing.net nuget package.
Maybe this code can help you or someone

Imports System.Data
Imports ZXing.Common
Imports ZXing
Imports ZXing.QrCode
Public Class Form1

```
Private options As QrCodeEncodingOptions

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    options = New QrCodeEncodingOptions With {
        .DisableECI = True,
        .CharacterSet = "UTF-8",
        .Width = 50,
        .Height = 50
        }
    Dim writer = New BarcodeWriter()
    writer.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE
    writer.Options = options
    writer.Options.PureBarcode = True

End Sub

Private Sub btn_GenerateQRCode_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_GenerateQRCode.Click

    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Then
        PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
        MessageBox.Show("Text not found", "Oops!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.[Error])
    Else
        Dim qr = New ZXing.BarcodeWriter()
        qr.Options = options
        qr.Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE
        Dim result = New Bitmap(qr.Write(TextBox1.Text.Trim()))
        PictureBox1.Image = result
        TextBox1.Clear()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btn_DecodeQRCode_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_DecodeQRCode.Click

    Try
        Dim bitmap As Bitmap = New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image)
        Dim reader As BarcodeReader = New BarcodeReader With {
            .AutoRotate = True,
            .TryInverted = True
        }
        Dim result As Result = reader.Decode(bitmap)
        Dim decoded As String = result.ToString().Trim()
        TextBox1.Text = decoded
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Image not found", "Oops!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.[Error])
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub btn_BrowseQRImage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_BrowseQRImage.Click

    Dim open As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()

    If open.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim qr = New ZXing.BarcodeWriter()
        qr.Options = options
        qr.Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE
        PictureBox1.ImageLocation = open.FileName
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnExportQRCodetoFolder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExportQRCodetoFolder.Click

    If PictureBox1.Image Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Image not found", "Oops!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.[Error])
    Else
        Dim save As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog()
        'save.CreatePrompt = True
        'save.OverwritePrompt = True
        'save.FileName = "MyQR"
        save.Filter = "PNG|*.png|JPEG|*.jpg|BMP|*.bmp|GIF|*.gif"

        If save.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            PictureBox1.Image.Save(save.FileName)
            save.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

End Class